# Get extra informations from Google API

Tags: api, google-plus, google-signin

I don't found any informations about extra fields that I might get like : city (location) of the current user (me).

By default the json response contains others informations. However I setting  both scopes : profile and email. (Is there any other scope that I have to declare to find the user city address like [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#tryit_email) ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These listed scopes are used to fetch the user profile.You can find the **placesLived** field in the users profile json array to know the location of the user.Try include **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me** in your authorization.

Comment: That change anything :/ The response contains this : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/458220jsonresponse.jpg

Comment: Try Using "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}" url end point with GET method to retrieve the user profile.This will give you a json array conatins user informations

Comment: You can also check the [link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_profile_information)